# Setting user and group for instance of invoice-ninja running on docker

Tags: docker, invoice-ninja

I have a quick question regarding the docker version of network-ninja [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/invoiceninja/invoiceninja/).

I'm running it on a docker host with a fairly complex host user / group structure and this is beginning to be problematic when setting the owner and access to mounted directories.

Several other containers that I run provide the ability to pass a variable to the instance to force it to run as a particular user / group that has previously been created on the host.

Does anyone know if this is possible with network ninja on docker?

Thanks in advance for your advice on this.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently this is not supported by the Invoice Ninja docker files. As the containers are built without any knowledge of existing users on the host systems, the app container (where Invoice Ninja runs) creates its own user called `invoiceninja` with it's own id `1001`.

The host mounted directories then need to owned by this id - see [details here](https://github.com/invoiceninja/dockerfiles#create-folders-for-data-persistence).

Comment: Thanks. This is possibly a problem if using multiple containers all using the same host id. Some containers are built with the ability to define variables that specify the user and groups that the container runs as. Do you happen to know if this can be accomplished somewhere in the build process?

Comment: Feel free to open an issue on [Github](https://github.com/invoiceninja/dockerfiles/issues). I'll see what I can do.